# Linebreak within \cvaddress

Tags: tables, letters, cv

I'm writing a CV using the following template:

https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/entry-level-resume-template-latex/jsmpwkcwyntg

I now want to add my address to the sidebar. By doing so I want it to look like:

```
Fake Street 1, 
01234 Fake Town
```

but all I can get is shown in the following picture:

[image]

I tried everything: `\par`, `\linebreak`, `\newline`, `\\`, ... 
but nothing seems to work as all of the examples mentioned above lead to significant errors.

Does anyone has an idea how I can make this work?

Comment: By default, the CV template you're using does not include an address. How do you add the address to your profile?

Comment: I just added 

   `\ifthenelse{\equal{\href{\cvaddress}{\cvaddress}}{}}{}{
            {$
              \begin{array}{l}
              \hspace{3.5mm} \huge \textnormal{{\faMapMarker}}
              \end{array}
              $} 
            & \href{http://\cvaddress}{\cvaddress} \\}`

in "twentysecondcv.cls" and used  `\cvaddress{Fake Street 1, 01234 Fake Town}` in "template.tex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are modifying the template `.cls` directly, you don't have to condition on whether or not you defined `\cvaddress`. You can just place the address and put the `\cvaddress` macro inside a `tabular`.

Specifically, I'd place

```
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\href{\cvaddress}{\cvaddress}}{}}{}{
  {$
    \begin{array}{l}
      \hspace{3.5mm} \huge \textnormal{\faMapMarker}
    \end{array}
   $} & {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l @{}} \cvaddress \end{tabular}} \\
%}
```

within the `\makeprofile` definition within `twentysecondcv.cls` (around line 210). It's strange to place the `\faMapMarker` part inside an `$\begin{array}{.} ... \end{array}$` construction when using `tabular` is all that is needed. If you're using a `tabular` instead, you may have to adjust the `\hspace` since the column separation differs between the two.

Now you can set your address using

```
\cvaddress{Fake Street 1, \\ 01234 Fake Town}
```

The address is set to be `[t]`op-aligned with `\faMapMarker` (remove it to be center-aligned).

[image]

If you want less spacing between the address elements, use something like:

```
\cvaddress{Fake Street 1, \\[-.5\normalbaselineskip] 01234 Fake Town}
```

A negative space in `\\[<len>]` brings the elements closer together.

[image]

Comment: That's an awesome answer! Thank you very much! It's exactly what I was looking for!